# What is the purpose of Pokemon moves, Celebrate and Hold Hands?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

So, I just read this articles about Pokemon moves, [Celebrate](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Celebrate_(move)) and [Hold Hands](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hold_Hands_(move)).

Both of them introduced in Generation VI Pokemon games and does absolutely nothing. Both of them also shares this trait with [Splash](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Splash_(move)) move that introduced from Generation I.

But not like Splash, both moves are event-exclusive move. Splash introduce because it have some related [Magikarp](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magikarp_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) that said it only can splashing around.
People will remember Magikarp if we're talking about Splash and vice versa.

So, how about Celebrate and Hold Hands? Are they have related with some event (in Pokemon of course) or they're just... umm... useless moves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whilst they seem to have no tangible benefit in-battle, Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire's Contests is another matter:

- **[Celebrate](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Celebrate_%28move%29)** gives 2 Appeal and will excite the audience, no matter what the type of contest is.
- **[Splash](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Splash_%28move%29)** gives a whopping 4 appeal in Generation VI but will make the audience quickly grow bored when an appeal move has little effect.
- **[Hold Hands](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hold_Hands_%28move%29)** Only gives 1 appeal but also prevents the user from being startled until the turn ends.

---

Unfortunately after extensive research I was unable to find any evidence that definitively proves or disproves whether Hold Hands has any effect on Pokemon's Happiness.

- The in-game description is:

  > Ally Pokémon hold hands. This makes them very happy.
- [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hold_Hands_%28move%29), [Smogon](http://www.smogon.com/dex/xy/moves/hold_hands/) and [Veekun](http://veekun.com/dex/moves/Hold%20Hands) list it as "No Effect" in battle
- [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/attackdex-xy/holdhands.shtml) does not list a secondary effect on the Hold Hands page, but on the [Event-exclusive moves](http://www.serebii.net/games/eventmoves.shtml) page they describe the move as:

  > This special move doesn't do much in battle, competitively, but is said to make the Pokémon very happy.
- From the Bulbapedia [discussion page for Hold Hands](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talk:Hold_Hands_%28move%29):

  > **Q:** So, does this really do nothing? Does it perhaps raise happiness?
  >   **A:** From what I've tested, if it does raise happiness it does so by a very small amount. It also doesn't boost Return.
- From a [PokemonDB question](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/204205/does-hold-hands-do-anything):

  > ...currently, there is no known effect of this move. I do believe it may increase the happiness, but we will have to wait and figure out what it does...

Until we can see some in-game testing or a trusted source that definitely lists it as proven or disproven I think the jury is still out on this one.

The other rumor that was floating around was that it boosted Happiness-based moves (i.e. Return), however this has been disproven, it provides no immediate benefit in-battle.

Comment: Hold Hands is also rumored to raise the target Pokemon's happiness, however as of writing I cannot find definitive proof for or against this, thus it does not form part of my answer yet. If I can confirm or deny this I will add it.

Comment: So, its more like moves for contest?

Comment: @JTR - Whether by design or by coincidence, yeah they only really have a tangible benefit in Contests. However as above I do recall somewhere saying that Hold Hands will raise the ally's happiness, making it useful for quickly raising happiness (useful for Happiness-based moves and evolutions, like Return or Crobat respectively)

Comment: ooh.. I see, I'm almost forget about contest. But, about raising ally's happiness, I think I need more proof, so lets see if anyone also saying about it. :)

Comment: Even if it did raise happiness, it's far more efficient to just make your pokemon hold a Soothe Bell, get on a bike, and ride in circles while you go do something else

Comment: @Pyritie - perhaps. Depends how its handled tbh. It may stack with Soothe Bell and befriending O-power, meaning all you need is ~5 turns of a battle (assuming ~50 points/turn similar to EV Horde training)

Comment: Both moves are effectively variants of Splash, i.e. they have no effect in battle. Any claims of raising Happiness are unsubstantiated rumors. http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hold_Hands_%28move%29

Comment: @MikeKellogg - see my edit. While it's unlikely Hold Hands has any effect on Happiness, this has not been proven or disproven in any way that I can see, just statements and rumors being made without any hard evidence. Until we can see some in-game testing or a trusted source that definitely lists it as proven or disproven I think the jury is still out on this one

Comment: @Robotnik That's what I said, unsubstantiated rumor. =P